# Compiling Visual Studio 2010 project in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt-creator

I am looking for possible answer or direction of whether it is possible to compile and integrate a Visual Studio project in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, However you can take all the files from you vs project (.h and .cpp) and add them to a qt project and they should compile, keep in mind that your going to be using the same compiler on windows irregardless of the dev environment